# How can I close my browser instance if my test fails in Nightwatch framework

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor, nightwatch.js, browser-automation

I want to close my browser instance whenever my test scenario fails,
The issue currently is my test execution proceeds to next scenario and because my last window is still looking for a locator or etc, even my next scenario fails.

Is there a way I can close my browser window if my test scenario fails in Nightwatch?

test_settings: {

```
default: {
  launch_url: 'http://localhost',
  page_objects_path: './e2e-nightwatch/ionic/objects',
  selenium_host: '127.0.0.1',
  selenium_port: 4444,
  request_timeout_options: {
    timeout: 7000,
    retry_attempts: 5
  },
  end_session_on_fail:true,
  skip_testcases_on_fail:true,
  disable_colors: false,
  screenshots: {
    enabled: true,
    on_failure: true,
    on_error: true,
    path: './e2e-nightwatch/ionic/screenshots'
  },
  desiredCapabilities: {
    browserName: 'chrome',
    javascriptEnabled: true,
    acceptSslCerts: true,
    "chromeOptions": {
      "args": ["start-maximized"]
    }
  },
},
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are probably observing, is not a `failure` but `error` (speaking Nightwatch language). This could be execution error, exception or something like that:

> ERROR: Unable to locate element: "#someElement" using: css selector

This is not considered failure (and failure actually means failed assertion), thus `skip_testcases_on_fail` option won't have any effect (btw: this option is set to `true` by default).

There are 2 ways to solve this.

**First (preferred):**

Before performing any actions on elements, for instance doing `.click('#someElement')`, the good practice is to run assertion on the same selector:

```
// fails immediately if element is not present
browser.assert.elementPresent('#someElement')

// wait for element to be present for specified time in ms
browser.waitForElementPresent('#someElement', 2000)
```

Both methods will stop execution of your test run in case element is not present.

**Second:**

In case you don't want to use the first method for some reason or just curious, there is another way to stop execution of entire test run.

Within the test case you can define `afterEach` function which is fired after each test case completes. Inside this function you have access to the object containing stats of the current test run. What you can do is to simply check if error count is greater than 0 and pass error to the `done()` callback which will lead into interruption of entire test run:

```
module.exports = {
    'Test case #1': function(browser) {},

    afterEach: function(browser, done) {
        done(browser.currentTest.results.errors ? new Error('Errors occured during the last test run') : null);
    }
};
```

Let me know if it worked for you.

Comment: Hi akrn I tried your solution above using an afterEach function and it didn't work for me, it just reports the error then carries right on and runs the next test. I also tried browser.end() if the browser.currentTest.results.errors was > 0 and that also didn't work.
Does it make any difference that i am using the CliRunner as detailed on [this page](https://nightwatchjs.org/guide/running-tests/#programmatic-api) in the Custom Runner example section.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah you can use `skip_testcases_on_fail` for this. In your config just add

```
skip_testcases_on_fail: true
```

This will finish out the current test step and then exit before executing any additional steps. You can see a full list of test settings [here](http://nightwatchjs.org/gettingstarted#full-list-of-settings).

You might also be able to use `end_session_on_fail`. Depends on how you want it to work.

Comment: Can you please confirm if I am using these parameters in the right way? I have updated my code above is my config file(part of it)

Comment: That is not working for me. Issue is more with the parameterized tests where I am using cucumber Examples to pass multiple data If my first test fails the cache is not cleared and hence on my next instance I log in when I click on login button(without need for username/password).

Answer (score -1):

```
Driver.Dispose();
```

Closes the browser.

Comment: Can you add some context here. Where and when would you call that?